# Run Visual Studio with Administrator Rights using app.manifest [ExecutionLevel]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I need to change the key in a registry in order to restrict the user from using Task Manager, since it is an Kiosk application. My code for changing the registry is working perfectly for Administrator account. But my application is going to be run in normal user account. When i tried to run my application in normal user account, i get the below error :

```
DisableTaskManagerSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: 
Access to the registry key 'HKey_Current_User\Software\Mictrosoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System' is denied.
at Microsoft.win32.RegistryKey.win32Error(int32 errorcode, String str)
```

So i need to run my application with all administrator privileges. For which i am using the below app.manifest. But some how i getting the same error. How to overcome this ?

Code in app.manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <ms_asmv2:trustInfo xmlns:ms_asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft- com:asm.v2">
    <ms_asmv2:security>
      <ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
        <ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true">
        </ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel>
      </ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
    </ms_asmv2:security>
  </ms_asmv2:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code requires an elevated privilege to access registry. However there is just a fragment of code that requires these extra permission. To handle such scenarios impersonation is used i.e. you will execute this application as normal user only but that particular piece of code will be executed as if you were an Administrator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx